# Is it ever OK to denormalize a foreign key relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following (simplified) MySQL schema:

```
companies
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

users
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email                | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| username             | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| company_id           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

notes
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| body            | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A company has many users, and a user has many notes.

My question is, is it bad to denormalize a little by adding a company_id
foreign key to the notes table? The reason is that then I can get all
the notes for a company with one fewer join than in the current schema.

Or to put the question another way: What are the pros and cons of adding
a redundant company_id foreign key to notes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do it. MySQL is very smart about joins. What seems like a lot of work in theory often ends up being done very efficiently. Use `explain` if you aren't sure about how much work a query will generate.

To save on typing up a join is a very poor reason to denormalize a data base.

Answer (score 0):

Disadvantages of de-normalizing (adding the company_id to the notes table):

- The data can get out of sync
- It uses a little bit more disk space

Advantages:

- Joins are simpler. Sometimes this *is* a good reason, for example: you could normalize an address table by moving the city name to a 'cities' table. But I wouldn't do it, because it will complicate a lot of queries, plus it will complicate inserts and updates, and there is little benefit. There is a way to reduce this 'added complexity' problem somewhat: using a view.
- For some cases it might be faster (those cases are rare).
- For very large databases, it might be easier to [shard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29) the data.